# Is Python's multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory.close necessary (in this case)?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Suppose this is the target function for a Process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import numpy as np

def target():
    sm = SharedMemory(name="foo")
    arr = np.frombuffer(sm.buf, dtype=...)
    # ... modifies arr
    sm.close()
```

So, the main process creates a chunk of shared memory and names it "foo". Then it starts
a Process(target=target). The process finds the shared memory by name and creates a numpy array whose data is the shared memory.
Changes in the array are actually changes in the shared memory. So far so good.

The problem is that sometimes the process is terminated. That means that sm.close() will not be
called.

This worried me for a while, but it would seem that the close is unnecessary in this case: when
sm goes out of scope its destructor will close it anyway. Or that's what I think. Am I right?

Comment: "when sm goes out of scope its destructor will close it anyway" - not if the process is terminated!

Comment: Well, the process is terminated, the target locals go out of scope, the SharedMemory object has zero references, its destructor is called, the destructor calls self.close()

Comment: No, the process is terminated, *the end*. The program doesn't keep running, not even to do cleanup.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just posted about this same issue with more detail.